# CAGradientLayer violet instead of red

Tags: iphone, ios

My question is simple.

I want to use CAGradientLayer to make a nice gradient background for my UIView.

But the problem is that it displays an ugly violet color instead of my desired wonderful red color.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:107 green:0 blue:27 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```

As a result, I can see that :

[image]

And that is not what I want... If someone can help me with this.

Thanks ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use fractions, not whole numbers:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:107/255.f green:0.f blue:27/255.f alpha:1.f];
```

Of course, be wary of integer division. That bastard always gets me in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

here you should use colour from RGB as

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
//here just set the colour form RGB.
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:exactFractionVal green:exactFractionVal blue:exactFractionval alpha:1.f]; CGColor];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}

//here exactFractionVal is the float value you should pass there for exact RGB.
```

you can find it on many website if you feel any problem n making the RGB.
here you can see the RGB Chart for making the Desired Color.

[here it is...!!!](http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/)

[here is another good link at where you can get quite good RGB for Red](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm)

i hope this may help you in what you needed..!!!

Comment: Nice tip, but I prefer to use the fractional numbers for better readability. Is there an advantage for using the exact fraction?